# Angular 11 AsyncValidator not returning error

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a basic form that checks if an email address exists as an Async Validator.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.form = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl('',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')
         ],
         [
           pendingPortfolioUserRequestValidator(this.portfolioInviteService, this.data.portfolioId)
          ])
      });
  }
```

The Async Validator `pendingPortfolioUserRequestValidator` looks like this

```
export function pendingPortfolioUserRequestValidator(portfolioInviteService: PortfolioInviteService,
  portfolioId: number): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return portfolioInviteService.checkUserIsPending(portfolioId, control.value).pipe(map((email) => {
      return (email) ? {'pendingUserExists': true} : null;
    }));
  };
}
```

The line of code that determines whether the email exists or not (`return (email) ? {'pendingUserExists': true} : null;`) is getting hit, but when I check the `errors` collection, it's giving `null` as the value.

I have also tried to use a promise, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check what value email actually gives in the response?

Comment: The response is returning ‘true’ from the api when the email exists, otherwise false. The problem is that the errors collection on the form control is empty, thus the validation passes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further [reading](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-custom-validators-to-reactive-forms), and trying to get to the bottom of this, I found a `pending` property.  When I checked the state of this, the property was still pending even though it looked like the validation was complete.  This part of the article helped with the understanding:

> Asynchronous validators implement the AsyncValidatorFn and
> AsyncValidator interfaces. These are very similar to their synchronous
> counterparts, with the following differences.
>
> - The validate() functions must return a Promise or an observable,
> - The observable returned must be finite, meaning it must complete at some point. To convert an infinite observable into a finite one, pipe
>   the observable through a filtering operator such as first, last, take,
>   or takeUntil.

I needed to add a call to `take(1)`, and this has solved the issue.

Updated Code:

```
export function pendingPortfolioUserRequestValidator(portfolioInviteService: PortfolioInviteService,
  portfolioId: number): AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
    return portfolioInviteService.checkUserIsPending(portfolioId, control.value).pipe(
      take(1),
      map(
      (email: boolean) => {
      return (email) ? {'pendingUserExists': true} : null;
    }));
  };
}
```